# Compositum of infinitely many unramified extensions is unramified

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

The fact that if I have two extensions of number fields, say $L_1 / K$ and $L_2 / K$, unramified at a discrete valuation $v$, then the compositum $L_1L_2 / K$ is unramified at $v$ can be proven directly. I'm now in a situation where I would like to take the compositum over infinitely many extensions $L_i / K$ each of which I know is unramified at $v$.

Knowing the result for two extensions can be used directly to see that the result holds for finitely many extensions. Is there an easy way to see that the result holds for infinitely many extensions as well? In my case, the compositum might have infinite degree over $K$.

Comment: What is your definition of an unramified infinite extension $L/K$? One definition is that every finite subextension is unramified, in which case you're done.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340749/96384

Comment: I see, honestly I had never thought about unramified extensions in the infinite dimensional case. When I ran into this statement I just immediately jumped to trying to leverage the finite-dimensional proof by some sort of inductive argument before I stopped to think about what the definition should be. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I think the union of those unramified subextensions is also a field?? For example for $x\in L_1/K$ and $y\in L_2/K$ unramified, $x+y \in L_1L_2$, which is again unramified, so it is also in the union.